# mongoose populate and sort nested item

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a simple model:

```
user = {
  'items': [{
        'name': 'abc',
        'pages': [ObjectId("58c703a353dbaf37586b885c"), ObjectId("58c703a353dbaf37586b885d"), ..]}
   }]
};
```

I'm trying to sort the pages of current item:

```
User.findOne({'_id': id}, {'items': {$elemMatch: {'_id': id2}}})
    .populate({path: 'items.pages', select: '_id', options: { sort: { _id: -1 } }})
    .exec(function(err, user) {

    });
```

But I'm getting an error: `Error: Cannot populate with`sort`on path items.pages because it is a subproperty of a document array`. What should I change?

Comment: It appears that this is a known, unfixed bug, according to the mongoose staff: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2202

Comment: Still unfixed from what I can tell. Recommended suggestion in that GitHub issue is to use builtin [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on the returned objects.